# Kill user session

Tags: java, session, servlets

I have 3 tabs. Home, tab1, tab2. When user launches the app, its directed to Home tab & I create a new session using `HttpSession session = request.getSession();`
When user browses to other tabs, I maintain the session using `HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);`
Now if the user click back on Home tab, I want to destroy the previous session and start fresh with new session. Please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace the code behind home tab by

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

if (!session.isNew()) {
    session.invalidate();
    session = request.getSession();
}
```

This is however a bit odd approach. I would rather put an attribute in the session and then intercept on its presence instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [session.invalidate()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

in jsp you can reset the session with

```
session.invalidate();
```

after that give the user a new one

Answer (score 1):

first use session.invalidate(); to destroy session

request.getSession(true);  will create new session if there is no session